# Run script in command prompt without exiting Python after

Tags: python

I run a script by entering "python filename.py" in Anaconda prompt. How do I run the file without exiting? (e.g. to introduce some function definitions, then use these definitions to do stuff in the prompt)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use

```
$ python -i filename.py
```

it does exactly what you want :)